# ajax load not loading textfile jquery

Tags: jquery, html

jquery load doesn't load text file ... i want to load text file on click ...its a sampl e program

```
    <div id="page">
        <h1>Demo Page - How to load page into div via ajax using jquery?   </h1>
        <table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="3" width="30%">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="loadPage">Click To Load Web Page</a><br />
                </td>                   
            </tr>
            <tr><td></td></tr>
            <tr>
                <td><div id="pagecontainer" /></td>
            </tr>               
        </table>
    </div>


<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        jQuery(function(){
            jQuery('#loadPage').click(function(){
                jQuery('#pagecontainer').load('sample.txt');
            });
        })      
    </script>
```

Comment: You need to post more than that to get any real help.  Post markup and possibly the directory structure.

Comment: try doing it this way `$.ajax({
            url: "./seeds/Ag.txt",
            async: false,
            success: function (data){
                pageExecute.fileContents = data;
            }
        });`
**REF:**http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11589387/load-txt-file-using-jquery-or-ajax

Comment: you're missing a closing semi colon on the closing of the dom ready function `jQuery(function(){..});` <--

Answer (score 0):

There must be an error somewhere (is your `sample.txt` file in the same path as your page?) or jQuery is not loaded. As this is working fine for me:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#loadPage').click(function(){
        $('#pagecontainer').load('text.txt');
    });
});
</script>
<a href="#!" id="loadPage">LOAD</a>
<div id="pagecontainer">
Here
</div>
```

Check out this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nd87/6CkEv/1/)

You may want to put an `alert()` just after the `$(function(){` to see if jQuery is actually loaded and working; should pop an alert on page loaded.

In case, post more of your code.