# how to read and store data from external file as variables javascript three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

i'm new to three.js so i apologize if this question has been asked before. i have this external .txt file that contains the x, y, z positions of 256 atoms.
the first lines of the .txt file goes as follows:

```
256
1 0.702825 2.71217 2.71612
1 16.9592 2.64886 6.79019
1 0.681418 2.68359 10.8911
...
```

the first row contains the number of atoms in the compound and the first column, the size of the atom. the remaining values are the x, y, z values for every respective atom. so far i added the first atom by manually inputting the position:

```
...
scene.add(sphere); 
sphere.position.set(0.702825, 2.71217, 2.71612);
```

can i open and read the .txt file line by line to store the next position in x, y and z variables? what can i do to use the external file's information?

Answer (score 1):

- You can use [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX) technology to get the file contents.

  ***Ex:*** [Read this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11589414/6568620).
- After that you can use [String#split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) function to separate your file into 
  lines and columns.

  ***Ex:*** [Read this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/96452/6568620)
- Then you can deal with it as an `Array`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API):

```
fetch('myfile.txt').then(response => response.text()).then(text => {
  const atoms = text.split('\n')  // split into lines
    .map(line => line.trim())     // remove whitespace at the beginning and end
    .slice(1)                     // remove the first line
    .map(line => line
      .split(' ')                 // split by ' '
      .map(Number))               // and parse the parts to numbers
    .map(([size, x, y, z]) => ({ size, x, y, z })); // create objects from the arrays
});
```

`atoms` should now contain something like this:

```
[
  { size: 1, x: 0.702825, y: 2.71217, z: 2.71612 },
  { size: 1, x: 16.9592, y: 2.64886, z: 6.79019 },
  ...
]
```

I'm sure you can figure out how to use that in Three.js.

Looping through the `atoms` could look like this:

```js
atoms.forEach(({ x, y, z }) => { // using destructuring
  // ...
  sphere.position.set(x, y, z);
  // ...
});
```

or:

```js
atoms.forEach(atom => { // normal forEach-loop
  // ...
  sphere.position.set(atom.x, atom.y, atom.z);
  // ...
});
```

or:

```js
for (let i = 0, len = atoms.length; i < len; i++) { // normal for-loop
  // ...
  sphere.position.set(atoms[i].x, atoms[i].y, atoms[i].z);
  // ...
}
```

Of course, you can use [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) instead of the fetch API.

Comment: atoms[i].x, atoms[i].y, atoms[i].z 
is this how you use the array?

Comment: Note that fetch is an "experimental technology" and is not supported by IE.