# Import <head> elements from another text file with html or client-side scripting

Tags: javascript, html, html-head

I am currently cleaning up a website's code. I've noticed that the `head` elements for every page is virtually identical. 
I would like to know if it is possible to put all the elements that are identical into a single text file then, in every html file, import the contents of that text file in some way.

I know that you can use `object` to accomplish this if the common code is in the `body` section but this doesn't work for `head`.

One more thing is that these web pages are hosted on GitHub Pages, so I can only use static pages and client-side scripting. If server-side scripting is available you can, for example, use `php import` to accomplish this.

If it helps, this is the common code I want to import into every page:

```
<meta name="description" content="A central resource for PC optimization information."/>
<meta name="keywords" content="Technology,PC,Computer,Optimization,Tweak,Guide,Tweaking,Microsoft,Windows,Nvidia,Intel,AMD"/>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="pi.css"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<meta name="MSSmartTagsPreventParsing" content="true"/>
<meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer"/>

<!-- Icons -->
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="apple-touch-icon.png?v=20191102"/>
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png?v=20191102"/>
<link rel="mask-icon" href="safari-pinned-tab.svg?v=20191102" color="#5bbad5"/>
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="favicon-32x32.png?v=20191102"/>
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="favicon-16x16.png?v=20191102"/>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico?v=20191102"/>
<link rel="manifest" href="site.webmanifest?v=20191102"/>
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#2d89ef"/>
<meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff"/>
```

Comment: You can, in theory load the header items (aside from JQuery) using an AJAX call. 
Basically storing your header.html as a single file and then appending it to the body as so: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11589387/load-txt-file-using-jquery-or-ajax

Comment: It depends on the framework.  If it is a static page, you can use CMS like OpenCms.  You can also use http://api.jquery.com/load/ if planning to add JQuery/JS

Comment: Does this answer your question? The same approach can be used for other elements [How do I include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but thanks for the assistance. I managed to figure out two scripts that will add elements to the webpage's head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the comments above and some research on my end, I managed to come up with the following scripts to add elements to the webpage's `head`. One requires `JQuery` and the other uses vanilla JavaScript:

**JQuery:**

```js
$(function(){
 $("head").load("../../aa_common_resources/common_head_elements.txt")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Vanilla JS:**

```js
var externaltextfile = '../../aa_common_resources/common_head_elements.txt'
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', externaltextfile, true);

request.onload = function() {
 document.getElementsByTagName("head").item(0).insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', request.responseText);
   };
request.send();
```